# How to convert double to string in blazor EditForm

Tags: blazor

blazor convert data double to string in EditForm

```
        <EditForm Model="@state" OnSubmit="@HandleSubmit">
           
            <p>
                <label>Nazwa</label>
                <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="state.Name" />
            </p>

             <p>
                <label>GTU</label>
                <InputText id="n" @bind-Value="state.GTU" />
             </p>
            <p>
                <label>Date</label>
                <InputText id="date" @bind-Value="state.Daty_Bay" />
            </p>

            <p>
                <label>Invoice</label>
                <InputText id="Invoice" @bind-Value="state.InvoiceNumber" />
            </p>
            <p>
       
                    <label>Profit</label>
                    <InputText id="profit" @bind-Value="Convert.ToString(state.Profit)" />
                
            </p>
    
      <button @onclick="() =>  HandleSubmit()" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button>
      <button @onclick="Close" class="btn btn-info">Close</button>
</EditForm>
```

in this form i get two errors :
first:
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer
second:
Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

How do i convert this data in the form ?

Comment: Yeah, you cannot do that. First of all, show us the definition for class of object state. Second, you cannot do a two way binding to a result of a function @bind-Value="Convert.ToString(state.Profit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the correct input component and everything works :

```cs
  <InputNumber id="profit" @bind-Value="state.Profit" />
```

Comment: Yes, get the right component and it works.   `InputNumber` is wired to handle the various number types as `TType`.